# Angular how to position the child component in center without adding style to td element in parent component

Tags: css, frontend

I have a parent and child component. The parent component html is simple table with td element. I want to position the child component to the center of the td element. Is there any better way to position the child component to center without adding class='centered' to the td in parent?

parent component html:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="centered">
            <app-courseformat-icon 
                [formatCode]="course.assignedFormat.formatCode"
                [tooltipText]="course.assignedFormat.formatName">
            </app-courseformat-icon>
        </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

`app-courseformat-icon` is the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
:host ::ng-deep app-courseformat-icon {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

Refer this stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-kmfxlc).

Comment: Thank you. Does this code has to be added to parent or child component?

Comment: You have to add this code in your parent component.

Comment: but instead add a simple style class in the parent component right as i have added in my query above?

Comment: That's actually bad advice. Deep manipulations are deprecated according to the angular style guide https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Ya @MukilDeepthi as per my understanding putting class on <td> is the simplest way but if you want to change the styling of child component's HTML  based on some condition in parent component then you should change the Encapsulation property or use the above properties. Refer stackblitz link I have added into the answer.